# How to save the result on the screen into a text file in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't understand it, I need all your help and I want know it too. Sorry for English language, I don't it well.

```
org 100h

.MODEL SMALL
    .DATA

            MSG  DB  0DH,0AH, ' ENTER THE STRING :-----> :  $'
            MSG2 DB  0DH,0AH, ' YOUR STRING IS  :-----> :  $'
            STR1 DB  255 DUP(?)
            ONE  DB ?
            TWO  DB ?
      .CODE

BEGIN:
      MOV AX,@DATA
      MOV DS,AX

      LEA DX,MSG
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H

      LEA SI,STR1
      MOV AH,01H

READ:
      INT 21H
      MOV BL,AL

      CMP AL,0DH
      JE  DISPLAY

      XOR AL,20H
      MOV [SI],AL
      INC SI

      ;CMP BL,0DH
      JMP READ



DISPLAY:

      MOV AL,'$'
      MOV [SI],AL

      LEA DX,MSG2
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H


      LEA DX,STR1
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H



     ; MOV AH,4CH
     ; INT 21H
      .EXIT



END BEGIN 


ret
```

Comment: As soon as you're talking "text file", you're starting to deal with file systems. What's your OS environment? (Also, I've added an x86 tag since there's more than one type of processor in the world, and they have different assembly languages)

Comment: @ctn - or some hobby system *modelled* on DOS. The reason I ask questions is to try to make sure that people are answering questions based on facts rather than assumptions, and to get the OP to think carefully about *specifying* their situation more carefully in future.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read the screen memory beginning at address `B800:0000`.

Check out: http://oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_23/CH23-1.html

And, more specifically: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/104081/104081/reading-a-character-from-the-screen/

For creating and writing to a file check out: http://devdocs.inightmare.org/tutorials/x86-assembly-dos-file-inputoutput.html

Comment: Or B000:0000h with an MDA or Hercules graphics card. (I run a production BSD server with one, they are not dead yet ;)

Comment: the last link is dead, here is the new link :http://devdocs.inightmare.org/tutorials/x86-assembly-dos-file-inputoutput.html